# Laravel nested relationship foreach loops

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, nested, relationship

I have this **relationship** betwen item and episode

item:

```
public function episodes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(episode::class);
    }
```

episodes:

```
public function item()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(item::class);
        }
```

In controller

```
$latestanimes = DB::table('episodes')->where('category', 'anime')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

What I'm trying to do is get the title of the anime it belongs to of each episode

```
                       @foreach($latestanimes as $episode)
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @foreach($episode->item as $parrent)
                                      {{  $parrent->title; }}
                                    @endforeach
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $episode->number }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $episode->category }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

This gives me "Undefined property: stdClass::$item"

I tried debugging in routes.php

```
Route::get('/dd/{id}', function($id){

        $episode=App\episode::find($id);
        echo $episode->name. '<hr>';

        $item=$episode->item;
        echo $item->title;

    });
```

And this works ... 
Is there a way to access it directly? like

```
{{ $episode->item->title }}
```

**Thanks** in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I was using query builder directly with `DB` which is not eloquent.

```
  $latestanimes = episode::with('item')  //eager loading, thanks lagbox
            ->where('category', 'anime')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

and I can access it directly how I wanted in the first place

```
{{$episode->item->title}}
```

Answer (score 0):

some problem in your code that is episodes model you are writing belongsTo that means a episodes has only one item that cause foreach loop does't work .